# Определить стиль, установленный у пользователя

Tags: android

В общем, в своем приложении я использую службу, которая вешает постоянную иконку в статус бар. Мне нужно определить, какая тема установлена у пользователя - светлая или темная, чтобы вывести соответствующий значок в трей.
С помощью поисковиков ничего подобного не нашел.

Как это можно сделать?

Заранее спасибо всем.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте GetCurrentThemeName (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773365(v=vs.85).aspx). Сам не пробовал, но наверняка некоторые имена будут содержать dark или bright.

А вообще, лучше не связывайтесь. Используйте прозрачные пикселы в иконке. Или GetSysColor(BACKGROUND_COLOR) (что-то в этом духе). Темы - это windows version-specific, понятие темы размытое (можно взять тему и поменять пару цветов) и т.д. и тому подобное.

Но на всякий случай, что ещё, как мне кажется, может пригодиться по этой теме:

> I found a registry key:
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes
>   which contains an entry:
>   "CurrentTheme" that gets populated
>   with the theme file name, not the
>   theme visual styles like the missnamed
>   API mentioned in my original post. For
>   example, for the Nature Theme, it gets
>   the value:
>   "C:\Windows\resources\Themes\nature.theme"
>   which is really good enough for me to
>   parse it and get the name. Of course
>   there would be a problem if the
>   theme's file name doesn't match the
>   actual theme display name in the UI,
>   but I will never hit that case in my
>   limited scenario

(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631796/how-to-get-the-windows-7-theme-name)

и http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18603/Advanced-UxTheme-wrapper

Comment: В тегах значится android.

Comment: Может быть мы чего то не знаем... :) и внутри там винда...

Comment: Прошу прощения, не заметил